# Python Global Variable Errors

Tags: python, validation, input, user-input

```
  global temp
   while True:
       Print("Please enter a text: ")
       text = raw_input()
   if text == temp:
       print("the same value")
   else:
       temp = text
       print(text)
```

I have this code to check if the user is repeating the same value, but getting below error:

```
NameError: global name 'temp' is not defined
```

I don't know why I declare the temp but got this error. Is there any other way to check if user keep on putting the same value?

Comment: `temp` is just declared, not defined...also don't use globals...

Comment: The statement `global temp` does not create a new variable `temp` and assign some default value to it. Python does not have "declaration" in that way.

Comment: @Kevin you Are true , he must define first  temp then Post his answer

Comment: don't use globals anyway. Pass needed arguments to your functions, and make your functions return computed values . globals are evil.

Comment: `temp` isn't even declared; `global` just indicates that the lookup algorithm should skip the local scope and look in the global scope for `temp`.

Comment: The `global` directive is used inside functions, to allow them to assign to global names. But there are no functions in your code, and a `global` directive in the global scope does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to use use global at all.

```
temp = ""  # Define empty temp
while True:
    text = raw_input("Please enter a text: ")   #write your print message in raw_input only
    if text == temp:  #compare with temp
        print("the same value")
    else:
        temp = text
        print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
Please enter a text: hi
hi
Please enter a text: hi
the same value
Please enter a text: new
new
Please enter a text: new
the same value
Please enter a text: new
the same value
Please enter a text: hi
hi
```

Comment: @SnowAngel That code _should_ do what you want. What does "the value of text doesn't pass with the temp" mean? Could you please try to explain that more clearly?

Comment: @SnowAngel, what are trying to pass, and what is the issue you are facing. added output as well

Comment: ok sir/mam it works now got some typo errors sorry thanks for immediate help so much appreciated :)

Comment: great, if this helps, would you like to accept the answer.